# Action after iteration in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

[image]I've build a model using the ArcGIS ModelBuilder. The model uses an iterator that clips all the features in a specific geodatabase. The iterator-part is nested in a submodel. I want that geodatabase ("Clipping-InputGDB") to be deleted after all the features within it have been clipped. Is there a way to do that?

Screenshot shows submodel.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting a delete tool in the master model. You make the sub model a precondition to the delete tool to ensure the correct order of execution.

Without testing, you might not be able to do it as you might get a schema lock?

Comment: I cannot make the submodel a precondition since only variables can be preconditions. But in this case with the iteration in the submodel, there is not a single output variable that could trigger a delete tool, no matter if it's inside the submodel or in the master model.

Comment: You could put in a Calculate value tool that checks the number of outputs being created (with a little bit of python) and that returns a True or False which you can expose as a parameter to be the precondition OR simply create a Boolean variable and set it to True and expose that if you know your clipping will always succeed?